# Splitting a string using multiple delimiters in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, variable-assignment, delimiter

I'm currently trying to split an array of chars that is assigned from reading in from a text file. right now I'm having troubles with delimiters and I don't know if I can have multiple. what I want to delimit is commas and spaces. Here is my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE * fPointer;
fPointer = fopen("file name", "r");
char singleLine[1500];
char delimit[] = 
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;


while(!feof(fPointer)){
    //the i counter is for the first line in the text file which I want to skip

    while ((fgets(singleLine, 1500, fPointer) != NULL) && !(i == 0)){
        //delimit in this loop
        puts(singleLine);

    }
    i++;
}

fclose(fPointer);

return 0;
}
```

What I've found so far is a way to delimit using a string of text that has shorthand for tabs and such e.g.

```
char Delimit[] = " /n/t/f/s";
```

then I would use this string in the strtok() method under the delimiter parameter

but this wont let me have a comma as a delimiter.

And the whole point of this is so I can start to assign the delimited strings into variables.

sample input: P1,2, 3 , 2

Any help or references is appreciated thanks.

Comment: `strtok`? Can you include a sample line from the textfile? What is the way 'you found so far'?

Comment: @thelaws I added some more information if you need clarification let me know.

Comment: You can use a `,` as a delimiter in `strtok`. There is an example of that here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: so I'd just add a comma to the delimiter array.

Comment: Unrelated, you had better hope that stream read really reaches EOF and avoids any stream *errors*, otherwise that outer loop never terminates. See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1322972) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `,` as a delimiter in the `strtok` method.

I also think you meant to use `\n\t` for newlines and tabs (I don't know what `/f/s` is meant to represent).

Try using this:

```
char Delimit[] = " ,\n\t";

// <snip>

char * token = strtok (singleLine, Delimit);
while (token != NULL)
{
  // use the token here
  printf ("%s\n",token);

  // get the next token from singleLine
  token = strtok (NULL, Delimit);
}
```

That would transform your sample input `P1,2, 3 , 2` into:

```
P1
2
3
2
```

Comment: The problem with the `strtok()` approach is the potentially incorrect interpretation of sequences of adjacent delimiters: `P1,,,2,3,2` would produce the same output, empty values cannot be parsed using `strtok`.